# How to close this dialog box

Tags: python, selenium

Hello Im trying to do web scraping In aliexpress website this is my code I want to close the open dialog

link= https://www.aliexpress.com/premium/spirited-away-socks.html?d=y&origin=y&catId=0&initiative_id=SB_20201114075955&SearchText=spirited%20away%20socks

First I get every product_name,price, and url.
THen I want to go to every url and get few things but the problem is the 'pop-up' box
I cant close it

```
driver= webdriver.Chrome(PATH)
ali=driver.get(r'[link][1]')
driver.implicitly_wait(10)
close_buttom=driver.find_elements_by_xpath('/html/body/div[7]/div[2]/div/a')[0]
close_buttom.click()
lista=driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="root"]/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[2]/ul')[0]
lista.text.splitlines() podría ser una opción a partir de aquí hacer scrap
titulo=driver.find_elements_by_class_name('item-title-wrap')
precio=driver.find_elements_by_class_name('item-price-wrap')
productos=[]

for title in titulo:
   enlace=title.find_element_by_tag_name('a')
   enlace=enlace.get_attribute('href')

for price in precio:
    productos.append([title.text,price.text,enlace])
```

Here is the problem I cant 'catch' the close button I have tried xpath and so on

```
    driver_2= webdriver.Chrome(PATH)
    ali=driver_2.get(productos[0][2])
    driver_2.implicitly_wait(10) }
```

If someone can help I would be very thanked

Thank you

Comment: Did you try to find the dialog button by its class name "next-dialog-close" and then click on it to close it?

Answer (score 1):

Two methods are available, either locate the element using selenium, in our case the class 'next-dialog-close', and then tell JS/Selenium to click the element that was located.

```
# using JavaScript (executed on page)
driver.execute_script('document.querySelector(".next-dialog-close").click()')

# using pure selenium/python
driver.find_element_by_class_name('next-dialog-close').click()
```

Comment: Using JS there is a correction  use this jS code inside execute_scripts method "document.querySelectorAll(".next-dialog-close")[0].click()"

Comment: Thank you for your answer but it isnt work in this case.

Comment: @JaimeGonzálezSuárez It worked for me. Did you get an error when you ran my code?